# How to bulge out a face?

Tags: modeling

Hi I have the following shape:

[image]

and would like to bulge out the top face like the side of a pill. I've tried inset faces with proportional editing, but the faces can only become so small before the vertices overlap and it goes crazy.

When I'm done I'd like a shape similar to one of these:

[image: pills]

Any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. Please share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look. Also, could you provide another image illustrating what you're trying to achieve? It will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Maybe you can try extruding up once more and then beveling the edge?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the stuff you asked for

Comment: Thanks Bert VdB, but I can't seem to get a smooth curve doing that?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this ? I can share the Blend file, but don't know how to upload it here... [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w2Jq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w2Jq.jpg) [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6865" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6865/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here comes a very simple way to do it:

1) Base
Add a circle with 32 vertices and a triangle fan.
Rotate it by 360/64 degrees along Z axis. This will get you nice flat sides.
[image]

2) Rim
Inset faces a bit to make a rim. All pills have a rim.
Then delete the triangle fan.
[image]

3) Fill the circle
Select 16 opposite vertices (exactly half).
Go to *Face->Grid Fill*.
[image]
[image]
Cool, right? Job done.

4) The bulge
Raise the middle polygon and enable proportional editing with falloff set to *Sphere*.
Play with the settings to your liking.
[image]

5) Create the bottom part.
Select all vertices *Select->All*, duplicate *Mesh->Duplicate* to make the bottom part.
You can use the mirror modifier for this, if you want.
[image]

6) Connect both parts.
Select those two edge loops and bridge them.
Edge->Bridge edge loops.
[image]
[image]

7) Add Subdivision modifier to smooth it out.
2 levels is enough.
Also set a smooth shading.
[image]

8) Change the shape to your liking
You can still change the shape and height in edit mode.
Just grab and move the vertices.
[image]

Example of final mesh.
[image]

Result:
[image]

---

Additional notes:
 - You can do this faster by using mirror modifier
 - Apply rotation, so modifiers work properly
 - There are many ways to do this, don't get hung up on this approach
 - Yeah... some pills have a groove in the middle.
 - Try it with different number of vertices, some will work better than others.

Uff.

---

Okay, here is the same pill with a groove in the middle.
It just felt so wrong without it I couldn't sleep.
[image]

Comment: nice... but how did you make it? :)

Comment: @RobinBetts This happens when I desperately want to show my ultimate modelling skills and forget I'm supposed to be helping others :)